# table-join selection performance: get members from nested groups (large amount)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

I have three tables which define member & group profiles like so:

> **[tbMember]** (1M records): MemberID(PK) | MemberName | Age | Sex
>
> **[tbGroup]** (10K records): GroupID(PK) | GroupName | ParentGroupID
>
> **[tbMemberGrouopRelation]** (2M records): MemberID | GroupID

Groups are ordered in hierarchical structure:

```
     /--- 2
1 --/---- 3    /--- 5
    \---- 4 --/---- 6
              \---- 7
```

When I grab some members from particular group (and all its subgroups), I write my SQL like (in SQL Server 2012):

```
SELECT m.MemberID, m.MemberName, m.Age, m.Sex
FROM tbMember m
  LEFT JOIN tbMemberGroupRelation mg ON (mg.MemberID = m.MemberID)
WHERE mg.GroupID IN (
    SELECT GroupID FROM FN_GetAllSubgroups(1)
  )
ORDER BY m.MemberID DESC
OFFSET 1000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 40 ROWS ONLY
```

Where FN_GetAllSubgroups implemented like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAllSubgroups] (@parentID int)
RETURNS @t TABLE(GroupID int, ParentID int, GroupName nvarchar(128))
BEGIN
    WITH GroupList 
    AS
    (
        SELECT GroupID, ParentID, GroupName
        FROM dbo.tbGroup
        WHERE GroupID = @parentID UNION ALL
        SELECT a.GroupID, a.ParentID, a.GroupName 
        FROM tbGroup a
            INNER JOIN GroupList b on a.ParentID = b.GroupID
    )
    INSERT INTO @t
    SELECT a.GroupID, a.ParentID, a.GroupName FROM dbo.tbGroup a
        INNER JOIN GroupList b on a.GroupID = b.GroupID
    ORDER BY a.ParentID, a.DisplayOrder
    RETURN
END

GO

-- index on tbGroup is ParentID (INCLUDE[GroupID, GroupName, DisplayOrder])
```

The function itself processes quite fast, even selecting from a top node group (returns 10k subgroups), processing time is within 200ms

However, when I do table join selection that select members from particular subgroup collections, it becomes extremely slow **(look at my first SQL)**. I checked execution plan and it tells me `Clurster Index Seek` on tbMember takes up to 97% of time, `Estimate rows = 1` and `actual rows usually >= 20K`

Are there any solutions to make it faster ?

Highly appreciate your help !

======================================

UPDATE: Execution result pasted below

> (40 row(s) affected)
>
> Table '_tbMember'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4679267, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table '_tbMemberGroupRelation'. Scan count 9516, logical reads 32484, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table '#AC4BBD06'. Scan count 1, logical reads 51, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>
> CPU time = 2953 ms,  elapsed time = 9143 ms.
>
> SQL Server parse and compile time:
>
> CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>
> CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

[image]

Comment: Rewrite your function into an `iTVF` and see if there's improvement.

Comment: Can you post your actual execution plan and schema of those tables involved

Comment: @TheGameiswar Is there a sample for posting execution plan ? It displays in GUI format and I don't know how to turn it into texts. TY!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan  ..you can use pastebin,if this is long

Comment: Have you tried HierarchyID and IsDescendentOf() to model your group memberships? I've had pretty good luck with that.

Comment: you mean creating an extra column for tbGroup which describes hierarchy level ? GroupID | GroupName | ParentID | HierachyLevel ? @BenThul

Comment: How to rewrite my recursive CTE function into iTVF ? I have no idea. Can you provide an example please ? @FelixPamittan

Comment: `CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAllSubgroups] (@parentID int)
RETURNS TABLE AS

RETURN

WITH GroupList AS(
        SELECT GroupID, ParentID, GroupName
        FROM dbo.tbGroup
        WHERE GroupID = @parentID UNION ALL
        SELECT a.GroupID, a.ParentID, a.GroupName 
        FROM tbGroup a
            INNER JOIN GroupList b on a.ParentID = b.GroupID
)
SELECT a.GroupID, a.ParentID, a.GroupName FROM dbo.tbGroup a
INNER JOIN GroupList b on a.GroupID = b.GroupID
   
`

Comment: TY! It works! almost 5 times faster than original query. when selecting members from top group node, it returns in about 2s. (compare to > 10s my version) @FelixPamittan

Comment: It would be an extra column of data type HierarchyID in which you pre-compute the group membership of each group. From that point, it's a matter of joining on `child.[newColumn].IsDescendent(parent.[newColumn]) = 1` to get all of the sub-groups.

Comment: can you post the content in answer section so I can mark this topic answered :P @FelixPamittan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try transforming your function into an `iTVF`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAllSubgroups] (
    @parentID int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 

WITH GroupList AS (
    SELECT
        GroupID,
        ParentID,
        GroupName
    FROM dbo.tbGroup
    WHERE GroupID = @parentID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        a.GroupID,
        a.ParentID,
        a.GroupName
    FROM tbGroup a
    INNER JOIN GroupList b
        ON a.ParentID = b.GroupID
)
SELECT
    a.GroupID,
    a.ParentID,
    a.GroupName
FROM dbo.tbGroup a
INNER JOIN GroupList b
    ON a.GroupID = b.GroupID
```